# Firebase retrieve multiple data using UITableViewCell (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I'm in trouble with retrieving data from Firebase.
My JSON looks like this:

```
-user
  -contacts
     -autoID Value1
        -contactName : A
     -autoID Value2
        -contactName : B
     -autoID Value3
        -contactName : C
(more contactName is coming, in same structure.)
```

But I have no idea how to get ALL contactName's Data(A,B,C....) then print in `UITableView` in Swift3.0

I want to make a result like this :

@In the TableView@

A

B

C

...

But My result is different, Maybe some problem in TableViewCell.swift... but I'm not sure

ViewController.swift :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell : MoneyTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MoneyTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MoneyTableViewCell

    cell.eachCell()
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()

    return cell
}
```

MoneyTableViewCell.swift

```
func eachCell() {

    dbRef = Database.database().reference()

    self.dbRef.child("user/contacts").observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in

        if let result = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {

            for child in result {

                let receiverNameDB = child.childSnapshot(forPath: "contactName").value! as! String
                self.nameArray.append(receiverNameDB)

                self.nameLabel.text = receiverNameDB
                print(self.nameArray)

                continue

            }
        }
    })
}
```

Can Anybody help me please ;)

**Update - I solved this problem! Here is my edited code... 
Thanks to @Abdul91**

The problem was.. I had to get the data from DB first, then put them in the array. After that get each data for tableView.

My edited code will tell you more.

ViewController.swift:

```
var nameArray:[String] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getNameDB{ value in
        self.nameArray = value
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    } 


    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "MoneyTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "MoneyTableViewCell")
}

//completion is for getting DB value outside of block.. 
func getNameDB(completion: @escaping (_ value: [String]) -> Void) {

    self.dbRef.child("user/contacts").observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in

        if let result = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {

            for child in result {

                let receiverNameDB = child.childSnapshot(forPath: "contactName").value! as! String
                self.nameArray.append(receiverNameDB)
            }
            completion(self.nameArray)
        }
    })
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.nameArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell : MoneyTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MoneyTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MoneyTableViewCell

    cell.nameLabel.text = nameArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()

    return cell
}
```

Comment: man you are tackling the whole problem in a very wrong way. You need to always first download and parse the data in an array and then use that array to populate the table view, not call the function for retrieval everytime in the cellForRowAtIndexPath. 
First problem you are having with is populating the array from firebase. correct ?

Comment: @Abdul91  Thanks for replying. So I should get all array from firebase first. .I'm wondering that Should i get data in TableViewCell.swift or ViewController.swift?

Comment: ViewController.swift and use data from that array to populate your cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Number of rows should be equal to the array size and thus each index of array will coresspond to each row in your table view.

Comment: @Abdul91 almost coming, but stuck in getting value outside of block with Firebase... :( I'll make it! Thanks

Comment: made it with completion()  :) yeah!

Comment: So your problem was solved and is working now ? Good to know. Let me know if need further assistance :)

Comment: @KUNWOOMYUNG Please share your working code with us:)

Comment: @Devhess I will

Comment: @KUNWOOMYUNG Thanks‘s mate:D